# How can I add local mounted volume to Plank?

Tags: dock, budgie

I'm using [ubuntu-budgie](https://ubuntubudgie.org/) and new to this flavour. I want to know that how can I add my mounted local volumes like `D:\` and `E:\` (NTFS partitions) to Budgie's Plank.

[image: Here is the image link to what I am mentioned as *PLANK*]

Comment: That's [a "Dock"](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/). I'm fairly certain that's the extension being used here, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ubuntu uses different terminology to identify partitions. /dev/sdxy rather than letters such as C: or E: . Windows uses letters but those letters do not mean much to linux.